# error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello everonye even I found many answers here about this questions one simply could not explain me how things going could not fix it trying everything.

So my question is I have a class called Matrix when I try to implement operator << as inline method I get following error

```
 error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
```

Here is how implementation of my method looks in class

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& out)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < this->getHeight(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->getWidth(); ++j) {

            out << this->(i, j) << "\t";
        }
        out<< "\n";
    }

    return out;
}
```

When I implement it as function like this

```
    template <typename U>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix<U>& c)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < c.getHeight(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c.getWidth(); ++j) {

            out << c(i, j) << "\t";
        }
        out << "\n";
    }

    return out;
}
```

It works :(
Can anyone explain me what I m doing wrong here

Comment: Does `this->(i, j)` actually compile??

Answer (score 1):

`std::ostream& Matrix<U>::operator <<(std::ostream&)` has the equivalent free-function signature `std::ostream& operator <<(Matrix<U>&, ostream&)`, which is ***not*** what you want (for multiple reasons).

It is not possible to implement streaming `operator <<` or `operator >>` as a member function of a UDT, because the first parameter must always be the stream. You could make the operator a `friend`, in which case the signature would need to be:

```
template <typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, Matrix const&);
```

(Again, note that the stream comes first, like in your working code.)

Your templated `operator <<` looks just fine. What's your objection to it?